# gIntersection results in a new dataframe with more rows

Tags: r, intersection, spatial-join, rgeos

This is my first time using rgeos::gIntersection, and I have a dataset with that I rasterized using rasterFromXYZ, then turned into a spatial polygon dataframe. I wanted to intersect this SP dataframe with a shapefile (in my case different nation's administrative regions). Reading the documentation for gIntersection, the result should respect the original dimension of my rasterized spatial polygon dataframe. However for some reason, while this is true for most of the countries, the result of the generated intersection has a lot rows than the initial dataset. I could not figure out why that is and why I only see this behavior for only one country.

The rasterized spatial polygon dataframe has 11073 rows, and the shapefile has 773 features. The result of the intersection generated 19267 rows of data. I have no idea why there are now an extra ~8000 rows of data and this is currently breaking some workflow (since I need to re-bind some of the attributes original dataset onto the resultant intersection layer).

I don't have easily reproduce-able dataset/code since the data I'm working on has PII, and it only is an issue for one country. But I wanted to see if other people know why this is happening? Am I mis-understanding how the function actually works? Is there a reason why this worked for other countries but not this one?

EDIT: after some investigation on the resultant intersected SPDF, I found that certain rows of data are duplicated (but not all rows), and the duplicated rows have unique shape area and shape len fields. I'm now super confused on why the intersected spdf generated duplicated values with unique shape areas?

Comment: Out of curiosity, does function `raster::intersect()`produce the same problems with your data?

Comment: It does produce the same problem, though from my understanding that is understandable since they use the same underlying algorithm to generate the intersection?

Comment: Right. `raster::intersect()` depends on `rgeos::gIntersection()` but the former returns the data.frames associated with the elements you are intersecting  (after merging if necessary). I wondered if that feature may provoke a different behavior and give us more information on your problem